# Why can't the Droid 2 connect to 5 GHz WiFi networks?

Tags: motorola-droid-2, wi-fi

The Droid 2 can connect to 2.4 GHz wireless networks, such as 802.11b/g/n, but not 5.0 GHz networks such as 802.11a/n.  Why is this?  Is there any workaround to allow it to connect to both types of wireless-N WiFi networks?

<sub>Note, this is similar to a question that was recently deleted by its owner and I didn't get a chance to answer.  Hopefully this will be useful to others in the future.</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The WL1271 WiFi chip in the Droid 2 does not support 5.0 GHz networks, so there's sadly no possibility of a workaround.  Its "better cousin", the WL1273 chip, does support 5 GHz networks; unfortunately, Motorola went the cheap route.  You can get more info on these chips at [the Texas Instruments website](http://focus.ti.com/general/docs/wtbu/wtbuproductcontent.tsp?templateId=6123&navigationId=12762&contentId=29993&DCMP=WTBU&HQS=ProductBulletin+OT+wilink_6).